# Pass value to stdin subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm trying to replicate this command in the subprocess library.

```
kubectl patch secret foo --type=json --patch-file=/dev/stdin <<-EOF
  [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/data/metadata/name",
      "value": "bar"
    }
  ]
EOF
```

How do I go about passing the below value via stdin?

```
<<-EOF
  [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/data/metadata/name",
      "value": "bar"
    }
  ]
EOF
```

Comment: You can always save this json as a tmp file and set `--patch-file` as a path to this tmpfile instead. I think it is easier than this stdin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting it working with similar to the following below:

```
def patch_secret(self, session):
     cmd = f'patch secret {self.secret_name} --namespace {self.namespace}' \
           f' --type=json --patch-file=/dev/stdin'

data="[{"op": "replace", "path": "/data/foo", "value": "TklFLXhmVnhsRHY4dnZMUEx0WXpJQ0M2bHl4Q1c4cElFdHpxeWFQN1VJTGs="}]"

r = subprocess.run(commands, input=data, env=envs, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True, **kwargs)
```